# Add dependency to android library

Tags: android, maven, android-library, jcenter

Base on this tutorial

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

I'm trying to upload my android library to JCenter/Maven so that my colleague can easily add it to their project like following

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mycompany.dev:library-name:1.0.0'
}
```

Problem is, one of my library is depending on other library such as ORMLite or Glide. When I run run

```
./gradlew install
```

I got this error

```
package com.bumptech.glide does not exist
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
..
package com.j256.ormlite.support does not exist
import com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource;
..
15 errors
100 warnings
:core:javadoc FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did your declare repository from which the library can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Either your own dependencies should be shipped as jar files inside of your APK (which might be a licence infringement), or your clients should add those additional dependencies in their build script.